# I'm trying to add data into my database from my website on visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a record to my database from my website but keep getting this mapping error

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strFirstName", txtAddFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strLastName", txtAddLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strCity", txtAddCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intStateID", ddlAddState.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strZip", txtAddZip.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intDepartmentID", ddlAddDepartment.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intLevelID", ddlAddLevel.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", chkAddActive.Checked ? 1 : 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intReasonForTerminationID", ddlAddReasonForTermination.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtmDateOfTermination", txtAddDateOfTermination.Text);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: "This mapping error"? You know we're not at your computer? We can't see your errors. You need to put the error in your question. And take the time to properly format your code. Actually think about how an outsider is going to view your question.

Comment: My guess would be SelectedItem returns an object.  You would have to cast it to the data type of the column.  SelectedValue perhaps, too.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intLevelID", ddlAddLevel.SelectedItem);
```

Returns an object not a value.  Try changing it to `.SelectedValue`;

Comment: Note that `SelectedValue` returns a string, if the parameter is expecting an integer value this could be problematic.  Obviously the fix would be to parse the string in that case

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this kind of code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intLevelID", ddlAddLevel.SelectedItem);
```

is something like a LineItem type but not a string and you have to pass a string value to the method